# Highcharts columns not displaying different color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and displaying columns but all the column colors are #7cb5ec. I tried to add a "colors:" array and even without the option, the default colors do not show. What can be wrong in my code?

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asle/yhkrcque/5/)

```
var colors =['yellow','#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        colors: colors
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Registreringer fra babkart.no',
        style: {'fontSize': '12px'}
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["Oslo","Arendal","B\u00e6rum","Asker","Larvik","V\u00e5g\u00e5","Skien","Porsgrunn","Tinn","Gran"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'poster'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        showInLegend: false,
        name: 'Antall registrerte poster',
        data: [1,13417,11745,10777,7919,6540,5873,4696,4122,4073]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Pottersky! The clue was **plotOptions:** block! I am sorry I did not see the other question. I must have asked wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try give your colours like this, Please check [this][1]

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/DwW3m/459/
```